# Several satellites crossing reference at uniform time intervals

Tags: conic-sections

How do we find relative positions of say $(n=16)$ satellites separated by a time interval $ \Delta T = T/16 $ crossing a reference radius orbiting a Newton ellipse?

Known in classical notation:  $(T,\,a,b,\dfrac{\pi ab}{T}=   r^2 \cdot d\theta/dt = h)$.

From the latter relation we get  for one pair in multiple occupancy orbit

$$ \dfrac{ h \Delta T}{p^2}=  \int _{t} ^{ (t+ T/n)} \dfrac{d \theta}{(1- e \cos \theta)^2}$$

Is it correct? How are true and mean anomalies employed to find position for each satellite? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You already know the physics stackexchange. I think it would be better if you asked the question there: https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/68712/narasimham

Comment: Thanks, would eventually move there depending on answers obtained.